# Jquery - инкемент в animate

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Никак не могу понять, почему у меня только один раз срабатывает click для простой карусельки.
Задача такая - ширина блоков не известна, количество блоков может быть разное.

```
$(function(){
        var list_item = $('.carousel li').length;
        var list_item_width = $('.carousel li').outerWidth();
        $('.next').click(function(){
            $('.carousel').animate({
            left: -list_item_width
          },1200);
        });
        $('.prev').click(function(){
            $('.carousel').animate({
            left: list_item_width - list_item_width
          },1200);
        });
       });
```

Пытаюсь для list_item_width добавить += или -= - выдает ошибку
Подскажите как быть с переменной?

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения свойства в таком виде `+=` или `-=` нужно писать в кавычках.

Т.е. в Вашем случаи должно быть написано

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  $('.carousel').animate({
    left: '-=' + list_item_width
  },1200);
});
```

Рабочий пример для работы кнопки `next`

```js
$(function() {
  var list_item = $('.carousel li').length;
  var list_item_width = $('.carousel li').outerWidth();


  $('.next').click(function() {
    $('.carousel').animate({
      left: '-=' + list_item_width
    }, 1200);
  });
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    $('.carousel').animate({
      left: list_item_width - list_item_width
    }, 1200);
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 700px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul li div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel-wrap">
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li>
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель. Не знал, что такой синтаксис можно делать. Работает как часы. Куда отослать благодарность?

Comment: :)  Никуда, достаточно принять ответ.